# Problemas con el DPR en srcset con media en picture>source

Tags: html, imagen

tengo un problema, agradecería mucho quien me pueda resolver la duda

1x no quiere funcionar al menos de que recargue desde herramientas en opcion responsive

Es muy  raro porque cuando recargo en una compu ( que tiene 1x) se carga es el de 2x al menos de que coloque modo responsive en Google  y me devuelva , no sé si es porque estoy en sublime y no tengo servidor local, ayuda plis

picture

source
srcset="img/perro-1x.webp, img/perro-2x.webp 2x" media="(min-width: 500px)" type="image/webp"

source srcset="img/Jolyne-1x.webp" media="(min-width: 350px)" type="image/webp"

```
  img
```

class="responsivo" src="img/JOJO.png" alt="JOJO" type="image/*"

```
picture
```

Disculpen, es que el código no quería integrarse, no se porque

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar un poco más tu pregunta? Un codesandbox o el código mejor organizado